# Dojo DOH unit testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, dojo, doh

I am a novice to Dojo, and I wrote a few unit tests following the normal convention and structure. I also have written tests for widgets.

I tried to run the tests using the same command I use for the unit tests:

```
java -jar path/to/js.jar path/to/dojo/dojo.js baseUrl=path/to/dojo load=doh test=path/to/test/module
```

The output says that there are no tests.

```
0 tests to run in 0 groups
```

My question is:

Is it possible to run the tests for widgets in command line?
Thank you all for your time

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you get a report saying "0 tests ... in 0 groups" - that implies that your tests couldn't be found rather than that they failed to run.

It *is* possible to run some limited tests for widgets from a command line, but you'll find various problems with that:

- if you want to use DOH Robot to run low-level automation, you'll find that that won't work, as it needs a browser 'window' object.  Try executing `node dojo\dojo.js load=doh test=dijit\tests\module.js` (or your js.jar instead of node) from the root of your Dojo SDK directory: you'll get lots of complaints about `window` not existing or that `registerUrl` hasn't been declared
- even if you could get that working, you'll be running tests with your particular implementation of JavaScript (and maybe some faked up implementation of some bits of a browser) and that won't be able to give you much confidence that your code will survive contact with a *real* browser with all its bizarreness

Comment: I was running this and in the test, got the error that 'document' is not defined. Is there a way to run DOH through PhantomJS or something to mimic a browser?

Comment: Probably not. DOH Robot needs Java applet support, which I'm guessing isn't present in PhantomJS?   You may want to have a look at theintern.io, which is set to replace DOH.